# Rails hierarchical relationship modeling users with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have this 3 models:

```
class UsuarioComun < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :usuario
end

class Operador < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :usuario
end

class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_one :usuario_comun
has_one :operador       
end
```

So I want that at the registration of a UsuarioComun create a usuario and also a UsuarioComun respectively but I cant make that with devise its only create a usuario, how I can fix that?

Comment: What attributes are on `UsuarioComun` that are part of your sign-up process?

Comment: name,company,birthday and all attributes of usuario

Comment: So, it's just going to be an empty record?  You can use a callback like the `before_create` callback to setup your new `UsarioComun`.  See docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: But how I create the registration form with which object?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  What is your overall question?

Comment: I have 2 types of user that share most of the information so I create a hierarchy. And now I want in a registration form create a UsuarioComun that have a parent a User, you understand?

Comment: You'll need to build it. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, seems your `UsuarioComun` model is basically a `Profile` model (stores extra user data not required in the authentication process (profile image, birthday, name, etc)

---

**Profile**

We implement this in most of our apps:

```
#app/models/usuario.rb
Class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :usuario_comun
    before_create :build_usuario_comun
end

#app/models/usuario_comun.rb
Class UsuarioComun < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

users
id | email | password | etc

usuario
id | user_id | name | birthday | etc
```

This builds a new associated record in the `usuario_comun` model, which basically means it's blank apart from the `user_id` column being saved

Hopefully this helps?

Comment: This solution is better than a hierarchy ??? And this code ":build_usuario_comun" do all the job of create one usuario_comun?